# Can I insert data from MySql by trigger into MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Lets say I have a System in place which exports data into a MySQL instance. Is there a way to react to those data changes (lets say with a trigger) and write/insert that data into my MongoDB instance?

ODBC Drivers for MongoDB exist, but I'm not sure it helps me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you looking for real-time synchronization between MySQL and MongoDB then you should use `tungsten-replicator` for same.
you can read more about it [tungsten-replicator](https://docs.continuent.com/tungsten-replicator-4.0/deployment-mongodb.html)

also, see it on [git hub](https://github.com/vmware/tungsten-replicator) project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This might be something I was looking for.